# Erro ao coletar informação de banco de dados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Estou tendo um problema ao obter informações de uma banco de dados, o código que tentei foi este:

```
require_once "config.php"; // database
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT conteudo FROM home NULL NULL NULL") or die("MySQL error:".mysql_error()); 
$result = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
echo $result;
```

Só que não acontece nada, não aparece a informação que peguei do banco de dados, alguma idéia do que esteja acontecendo?

OBS: Caso seja algum erro na página, aqui vai o código:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Trilhas da Terra</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div id="menu">
<ul class="main">
<li><a class="item" href="index.html"><div>Home</div></a></li>
<li><a class="item" href="quem.html"><div>Quem Somos</div></a></li>
<li><a class="item" href="roteiros.html"><div>Roteiros</div></a></li>
<li><a class="item" href="portfolio.html"><div>Portfolio</div></a></li>
<li><a class="item" href="contato.html"><div>Contato</div></a></li>
<li style="float:right;"><a class="item" href="login.html"><div>Admin</div></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="logo"><img src="imagens/logo.jpg"></div>
<div id="info">
<div id="wtitle">Home</div>
<br>
<div id="wcont">
<?php
require_once "config.php"; // database
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT conteudo FROM home NULL NULL NULL") or die("MySQL error:".mysql_error()); 
$result = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
echo $result;

?>

</div>
</div>
<div id="widside">
<div id="wtitle">Trilhas do Barro Serra do Mar</div>
</div>
<script src="some.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Esse `NULL NULL NULL` é bem suspeito, já tentou tirar isso da query?

Comment: Sim, não mudou nada, os NULL's servem para WHERE ORDER e LIMIT

Comment: Mas eu acho que esses NULLs dão erro de sintaxe. E não está dando nenhum erro? Se você der um `var_dump($result)`, o que aparece?

Comment: Não apareceu nada, estranhei, então coloquei somente um echo e um texto, não apareceu, parece que é algum erro na colocação do código, vou editar a pergunta e colar o código da página

Comment: Pronto, veja se consegue achar algo errado.

Comment: Coloque isto no início do seu código PHP, acima do `require_once`: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Ok, apareceu que era erro de sintaxe por causa do NULL então tirei eles, agora não apareceu nada, nem o conteudo do bd nem algum erro.

Comment: Tentou o `var_dump`?

Comment: retornou: boolean false

Comment: Isso quer dizer que está dando erro na execução da query. Pode ser um problema de conexão ao banco (verifique se está tudo certo no arquivo que está sendo incluído). Pode também ser erro no nome da tabela ou da coluna no seu select. Outra coisa: não se deve mais usar as funções `mysql_`, elas estão sendo descontinuadas. Use `mysqli` ou PDO (leia o aviso em vermelho [aqui](http://br2.php.net/mysql_query)).

Comment: Esta sentença SQL: "SELECT conteudo FROM home NULL NULL NULL" está sintaticamente errada. Veja: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: possível duplicata de [mysql\_query retornando falso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8027/mysql-query-retornando-falso)

Answer (score 2):

Se você não deseja criar nenhuma cláusula para a sua consulta, basta não digitar nada, os `NULLS` que você adicionou estão acusando erro de sintaxe. Deixe a sua query da seguinte maneira `mysql_query("SELECT conteudo FROM home")` que deverá funcionar.

Lembrando sempre que: 'conteudo' refere-se a COLUNA, enquanto 'home' é a TABELA do banco de dados e não o nome do banco em si. Você deve ter feito alguma confusão com relação a estes conceitos. Caso não obtenha êxito, certifique-se de que o arquivo `config.php` está realizando a conexão com sucesso e de que o nome da coluna e da tabela foram digitados corretamente.