# mysql_query retornando falso

Tags: php

Estou tentando pegar informações do meu banco de dados mais ele não está retornando o conteúdo, somente  um booleano falso:

```
require_once "config.php"; // database
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM home") or die("MySQL error:".mysql_error()); 
$result = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
var_dump($result);
//echo $result['conteudo'];
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) {
  echo $info['conteudo'];
}
```

Uma foto do resultado: http://prntscr.com/2xu5to 
Alguma ideia do que possa estar acontecendo?

Comment: possível duplicata de [Erro ao coletar informação de banco de dados](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8015/erro-ao-coletar-informacao-de-banco-de-dados)

Comment: Acredito que o erro seja outro

Comment: Mas na outra pergunta não chegamos a nenhuma conclusão sobre o erro. É o mesmo código, dando o mesmo problema. Por isso eu considero a mesma pergunta...

Comment: Na verdade o outro problema se tratava de não estar acontecendo nada, e esse se trata do resultado retornando um booleano em vez do texto, não faria sentido editar a outra pergunta...

Comment: Tem alguma coisa na tabela `home`? O `mysql_fetch_array` só retorna `false` quando o resultado é vazio.

Comment: Sim, como pode ver nessa foto: http://prntscr.com/2xu87c

Comment: Esse print mostra que a tabela tem uma coluna definida, mas não que ela contém dados.

Comment: Aliás, home é mesmo uma tabela ou é o nome do banco?

Comment: é uma tabela, e eu achei um problema, aparentemente não tinha sido criado os dados que eu tinha inserido, criei e agora aparece isso na página:
array (size=2)
  0 => string '�' (length=1)
  'conteudo' => string '�' (length=1)
0

Comment: Problema resolvido então? Postei meu comentário como resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se `mysql_fetch_array` está retornando `false`, é porque não há dados na sua tabela. Certifique-se de inserir os dados antes de fazer o `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

Se você não passa o identificador da conexão obtido antes com a função mysql_connect, o PHP vai conectar com um banco dadas pré-definido na configuração do PHP (ou não) quando usa mysql_query, mas essa conexão pode não ter sido estabelecida porque o endereço servidor de MySQL não está bem configurado.

Não é recomendado não passar parâmetro do identificador de conexão por causa disso.